# Parent and child css relationship?

Tags: css

Is it possible to write a child css inside the parent's css?
[the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/70/)

-Before-

```
table.header {
    line-height:32px;
    background-color:#1BA7F5; 
    color:#FFF;
}

table.header th {
    padding-left:10px;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

-After- (I have tried the below and it doesn't work)

```
table.header {
    line-height:32px;
    background-color:#1BA7F5; 
    color:#FFF;
th {
    padding-left:10px;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: On the nested CSS part of this, consider Sass http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3

Comment: Your first two questions would be more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com. The third is not possible in plain CSS, maybe LESS can do it.

Comment: jdphenix and Barmar, thank for the information on SASS and LESS. So it is like a library for CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain CSS it's not possible. If you set a class on the header tags you can target them with a single selector.

Using something like [less](http://lesscss.org/features/), you can do:

```
table.header {
    line-height:32px;
    background-color:#1BA7F5; 
    color:#FFF;
th {
    padding-left:10px;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
}
```